# Create a subdirectory in bash based on $1

Tags: bash

I have a HD full of directories named for CD albums which contain *.wav files.

I want a bash script that takes $1: **mp3-squeeze kind_of_blue**

and the script changes dir to "kind_of_blue", 
creates a directory called $1_MP3 example: "kind_of_blue_MP3",

and lame outputs the mp3's to the newly created "kind_of_blue_MP3" directory.

Sadly, what I have creates "$album" not "kind_of_blue_MP3". Anyone have a solution?

```
#!/bin/bash
#to convert .wav to .mp3 using lame utility

album=$1

cd $album

mkdir -p '$album_MP3'

for i in *.wav ; do
  echo $i
  bname=`basename $i .wav`
  lame --preset fast extreme $i $bname.mp3
done

mkdir mp3 && mv *.mp3 mp3
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong quotes. Plus, you have to end the variable name.

```
mkdir -p "${album}_MP3"
```

Comment: @verlager you should also use double-quotes around all variable references (e.g. `cd "$album"`, `basename "$i" .wav` etc) in case any filenames have spaces or other funny characters.